# Have to and be+going to difference

Tags: sentence-meaning

As far as I understand, both "have to" and "be + going to" are used in future action.

So, for example I have an exam in 2 hours, which one should I say?

1. I think I have to study now because I have an exam in 2 hours.
2. I think I'm going to study now because I have an exam in 2 hours.

What's the main difference? Are those interchangeable?

I read a book and it said **have to** expresses the idea that something is necessary and **be + going to** is used when I want to do something. In my case, I want to study, so, aren't they have the same meaning? By the way I've tried to look for possible duplicate but I couldn't find any. Hope you can help me to understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. "I have to"
2. "I'm going to"

These two examples have different meanings, as you have checked too.

As you *want to* study though you *do not need to*, the second example is better.

https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/have-to

> have to
> auxiliary verb

> (used with the infinitive form of another verb) to need to or be forced to; must:

> I have to go to Vermont tomorrow.

https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/future-be-going-to-i-am-going-to-work

> Future: be going to

> Intentions

> We use be going to to talk about future plans and intentions. Usually the decision about the future plans has already been made:

> She’s going to be a professional dancer when she grows up.